# How to solve GUI problems (place_forget, picture place, GUI not responding )?

Tags: python, tkinter, label, png

```
label2 = Label(root, text="STOP!", font=font)
label3 = Label(root, text="WAIT!", font=font)
label4 = Label(root, text="GO!", font=font)

TrafficLightOff = Image.open(__file__+"/../bg1.png")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(TrafficLightOff)
TrafficLight = Label(root, image = photo, background="white")
TrafficLight.pack(side=TOP)

TrafficLightRed= Image.open(__file__+"/../bg2.png")
photo1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(TrafficLightRed)
TrafficLightONRed = Label(root, image = photo1, background="white")

TrafficLightYellow= Image.open(__file__+"/../bg3.png")
photo2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(TrafficLightYellow)
TrafficLightONYellow = Label(root, image = photo2, background="white")

TrafficLightGreen= Image.open(__file__+"/../bg4.png")
photo3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(TrafficLightGreen)
TrafficLightONGreen = Label(root, image = photo3, background="white")

def STARTSTOP():
    if STARTSTOPBtn['text']=='START':
        STARTSTOPBtn['text']='STOP'
        TrafficLight.place_forget()
        while True:
            if STARTSTOPBtn['text']=='STOP':
                TrafficLightONRed.pack(side=TOP)
                print("red")
            
                label2.place(x=200, y=100, relwidth=5, relheight=.08, anchor="center")
                time.sleep(15)
                label2.place_forget()
                TrafficLightONRed.pack_forget()

            
                TrafficLightONYellow.pack(side=TOP)
                print("yellow")
            
                label3.place(x=200, y=100, relwidth=5, relheight=.08, anchor="center")
                time.sleep(15)
                label3.place_forget()
                TrafficLightONYellow.pack_forget()

            
                TrafficLightONGreen.pack(side=TOP)
                print("Green")
            
                label4.place(x=200, y=100, relwidth=5, relheight=.08, anchor="center")
                time.sleep(15)
                label4.place_forget()
                # TrafficLightONGreen.pack_forget()
            else:
                break



    elif STARTSTOPBtn['text']=='STOP':
        STARTSTOPBtn['text']='START'
        TrafficLight.pack(side=TOP)


STARTSTOPBtn =Button(root, text="START", font=font, command=STARTSTOP, relief="ridge")
STARTSTOPBtn.place(x=200, y=620, relwidth=.2, relheight=.08, anchor="center")
```

I had made a `Tkinter` application but I face some problem like

1. I give `TrafficLight.place_forget()` but it doesn't remove the place of the picture
2. I had made an infinite loop having `sleep` for 15sec but it doesn't give me the next picture and label and it only gives print function
3. When I press the start button my GUI is not responding.

Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Your `STARTSTOP` function needs to complete. That loop you have running should be in a separate thread. I don't think the command will re-enter that function.

Comment: There is something I would recommend that is not related to the error of your code but is very important: never use `from tkinter import *`. Do you know that tkinter has also a class named Image? The tkinter Image class does not have an open attribute, which may lead to an error when doing `Image.open`.

Comment: @TomMyddeltyn How can I use threading in a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy to solve. Everything is happening as it should, the image is being changed and place and label forget is happening, but it is happening in an infinite loop and nowhere there it is being said to update the root. So you can't see what is happening. If you place `root.update()` before each `time.sleep` like the example bellow, it will work:

```
label2.place(x=200, y=100, relwidth=5, relheight=.08, anchor="center")
root.update()
time.sleep(5)
label2.place_forget()
TrafficLightONRed.pack_forget()
```

the GUI is not responding because 15s is a lot of time and during the time.sleep you can't interact with the GUI

Comment: using `time.sleep` is not recommended. During that time the GUI will be completely frozen.

Comment: @BryanOakley, he could use `after` instead of `time.sleep` if he doesn't want to block the execution. I did this way because I believe it is important him to know that his program was working the way he did.

Comment: @Flovio Moraes Thank you, sir, as your suggestion (root.update()) it works successfully

Comment: I can't give you an upvote due to my reputation is low.